# Display custom post type from template

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I have this template file called Events. The purpose of this file is just to display the latest post with custom type Event. I have solved it with a very ugly solution. There must be a simpler and more correct way to do this. If you check my code im sure you understand what im trying to accomplish :)

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Event
*/
?>

<?php
$permalink = get_permalink($wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'event' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1"));
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "<?php echo $permalink; ?>";
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Cleaner solution:**

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Event
*/
$permalink = get_permalink($wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'event' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1"));
header('Location: '.$permalink);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the proper archive page (e.g. `example.com/events`), make sure that you register your custom post type with `'has_archive' => true` and then create an `archive-events.php` in your theme (changing `events` to whatever you've named your CPT).

To show just the latest post, put the following before you call your loop stuff:

`global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=1' );`

If you just want to redirect to that latest one, which seems less elegant, try putting the above right at the beginning, starting the loop, and then use PHP `header()` to redirect, probably using `302` as the reason. Be sure that there is **no** output (even empty lines outside of PHP code) before you call `header()`. Also be sure to have some kind of fallback in case there is no matching post for the query.

Comment: Well i just want to redirect to the latest post, i tried using the code in my example but instead of the html and window.location javascript i used header. That resulted in an error saying "headers already sent". Any ideas?

Comment: Solved it by removing some blankspace in my php file! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked, though I'd still advise having some kind of fallback in case there is no matching post :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do anything other than register your post type appropriately: 
See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters

with   publicly_queryable = true  (I think the default is false)

Then it will automatically have a template.  It will use the single post if there is no custom template.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display.

See also http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress

Working Example here: (uses default template single post. Has a filter to add some event data in to the content for event post types):
http://test.icalevents.com/event/bunny-hop/